# Number of ways to have two heart cards next to each other in a standard deck

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

So, in a standard deck of $52$ cards, there are $13$ hearts $\heartsuit$. Say you want to calculate all the different ways a deck can be arranged so that two heart cards are always next to each other.

What I did was calculate $\frac{13!}{2! \times 11!}$ which is different ways you can get a pair of hearts, then calculate $2 \times 51!$, which is the way you can arrange a deck where at least one pair of hearts exists (multiply by $2$ because the pair can have different order). So the total would be $\frac{51! \times 13!}{11!}$. Is this correct?

Comment: No, because you are counting arrangements with more than one hearts pair multiple times (once with one pair chosen as your two hearts cards, once with the other pair chosen). Instead you are better off counting how many arrangements have no adjacent pair of hearts, and subtracting that from the total number of possible arrangements.

Comment: A quick test to see that it is wrong, even if you don't see the idea @JaapScherphuis gave: There is a total of $52!$ ways to arrange the cards. Your number is already bigger than that, so that can't be the right answer.

Comment: A little nitpicking: I guess I got your intended meaning, but "two heart cards are always next to each other" would also mean that there are no lonely hearts: every heart belongs to s group of at least two.

Comment: Hint:  counting the lists in which there is no pair of Hearts is a [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) problem.  First list the $13$ hearts.  Now you  have gaps between the hearts (and in front of the first and after the second).  Distinguish cases in which the initial gap is empty, final gap empty, both empty, neither empty.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you meant you want to count the number of permutations of the deck in which at least two hearts are adjacent, we can count the complement as follows:

1. Arrange the other $39$ cards in the deck.
2. This creates $40$ spaces, $38$ between successive cards and two at the ends of the row.  To ensure that no two hearts are adjacent, choose $13$ of these $40$ spaces.
3. Arrange the $13$ hearts in the selected spaces.

> $$39!\binom{40}{13}13!$$

Subtracting this from the $52!$ arrangements of the deck will give you the desired total.